# Instead of using single() to return one item in a table, how can I return multiple items tied to the same ID in a list?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, sequence, razor-pages

I'm creating a contact management database as a project and using razor pages have created tables of contacts and activities.  On the individual contact's page I would like to return a list of all activities tied to their ID rather than just a single activity.  Here is how I set up:

```
public Contact Contact { get; set; }
public List<Activity> Activity { get; set; }

public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    Contact = await _context.Contact
        .Include(c => c.Location)
        .Include(c => c.Role)
        .Include(c => c.State).FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ContactID == id);

    Activity = await _context.Activity
        .Include(c => c.ActivityTask)
        .Where(m => m.ContactID == id)
        .ToListAsync();

    if (Contact == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return Page();
}
```

Then I am calling each item to display like so:

```
<dt class="col-sm-2">
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Activity.Single().Status)
</dt>
<dd class="col-sm-10">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Activity.Single().Status)
</dd>
```

Obviously single will throw an exception, but I'm not sure what to replace it with.  I thought maybe Where() or FindAll() but neither worked in my current setup.

Comment: since you are filtering with `ActivityTask`, i.e. `.Include(c=>c.ActivityTask)` could be possible you end up with only one record. Did you check backend what exactly total records present for a contact based on activity?

Comment: I was successful getting a single activity to appear, but when any additional were added received an error due to my use of single().    There are several other fields we display from, I just copied one in here for reference.  Also, I included activity task there as it is a piece of data from another table I wanted to include in my results.  Activitytask is a foreign key on the activity table.  Does that make sense?

Comment: `Include` does not filter, it only populates navigation properties.

Comment: Could you show the whole page, pls?

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose between turn your razor code to render a list of activities:

```
@foreach (var item in Activity)
{
    <...
}
```

or use `.FirstOrDefault()` and render only the first.

Regards.

Comment: Just to note: `Include` transpiles in Left Join, so it can't be filtering your results.